# Behaviour of Table.getNumberOfRows()

Tags: itext, itext7

The iText `Table.getNumberofRows()` fn returns the number of rows in a table, and generally works as expected. If the last row only contains a partial number of Cells it still counts as a row, which makes sense. However if it doesn't contain *any* cells, I don't think that's a row, so it shouldn't count. Unfortunately it does. For example, when a Table is first created, getNumRows() returns 1 rather than 0. (This is because in its constructor it (sensibly) calls an init fn which prepares an empty row.)

Now, if you add a full line of cells to the table, getNumRows() still returns 1, so you can't tell an empty table from a valid one-liner. A workaround is to call `startNewRow()` after each line of cells is added, and handle the consequence that `getNumRows()` will be one too big. On 7.0.2, though, this workaround has started generating a warning message about `Last row is not completed. Table bottom border may collapse as you do not expect it`. It's not wrong, but it looks bad.

Could you update iText to treat a row with no cells as no row at all?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. This seems reasonable and it will be considered.

Comment: Thanks, Alexey. I did try using Table.getCell(0,0) to see if the first row existed or not, but this throws an exception (rather than returning null, as the docn suggests) on a new Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vernon.

I believe you can use table.isEmpty() to check whether Table has some children (cells) or not. If the result is true, the row exists indeed.

But fortunately (thanks for your suggestions) we've fixed the problem (see [`7.0.3-SNAPSHOT`](https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/snapshot/com/itextpdf)). Now Table will have empty row list until one adds a cell. So the result of table.getNumberOfRows() will be correct.

Comment: That was very quick! Many thanks. I couldn't see isEmpty() in the API docn, so didn't know about it.